# Sorting by linkable associations (i.e. resources to top-level resources) is not supported

Tags: sorting, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have been using Spring Data REST in a few projects lately, and I really love it.

In the latest release (2.6.1.RELEASE) I have noticed this addition to the documentation under section 6.2.

> Sorting by linkable associations (i.e. resources to top-level resources) is not supported.

What is the reason for this limitation?

Is there anyway to bypass this limitation?

Thanks!